# Return a class to be created later

Tags: java

Currently, I'm migrating a game from Python to Java. In it, I created a Generator that returns a "class" that will be created with arguments its caller would have, like so:

```
package me.mathmaniac.smallworlds.world.generation;



import me.mathmaniac.smallworlds.block.Block;
import me.mathmaniac.smallworlds.block.NullBlock;
import me.mathmaniac.smallworlds.world.LayerType;

public class FlatGenerator implements Generator {

  @Override
  public Block generateBlock(LayerType ltype, int x, int y) {
    switch (ltype) {
      case Liquid:
        return HoleBlock;
      case Solid:
        return GrassBlock;
      case Air:
        return AirBlock;
      default:
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
  }

}
```

Called from here:

```
package me.mathmaniac.smallworlds.world;

import me.mathmaniac.smallworlds.block.Block;
import me.mathmaniac.smallworlds.world.generation.Generator;

public class World {

  Generator generator = ...;

  // ...

  private void generateBlocks(int x, int y) {
    for (LayerType ltype : LayerType.values())

      setblock(generator.generateBlock(ltype, x, y).new(x, y, ltype), //.new() is as an example
         x, y, ltype);
  }

}
```

How would I accomplish this in Java?

Comment: You could have an interface `BlockGenerator` and have a `generateBlock()` method in it that returns the proper `Block` subclass. I don't have time to make a complete answer, but this should be a starting point for you, or someone writing an answer.

Comment: I don't think your `switch` statement will compile.  It is possible in JDK 7 or later to `switch` on strings, but not objects.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I'm using Eclipse / jdk 1.7.0 and - other than the "return NullBlock" thing, it's working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the [Factory Pattern](http://howtodoinjava.com/design-patterns/implementing-factory-design-pattern-in-java/)

You would have a few classes: an abstract class `Block` (or an interface) and the factory class `BlockFactory` (or as you called it, `FlatGenerator`).

If there are a number of functions that can have the same implementation across all Block types, then make the base class `Block` be an abstract class and put those methods in there. Otherwise, you can use an interface.

Comment: I hoped I wouldn't have to instantinate the class right there, but it looks like I have to. Thanks.

Comment: @MathManiac you don't. You could instead return the class object and use that to instantiate later but i don't see any benefit to that and a lot of disadvantages

Answer (score 0):

One approach could be to give all your layer classes the same interface and a no-argument constructor, and return `Class<T>` object from the method that returns the class to be instantiated later:

```
interface Layer {
    void init(LayerType ltype, int x, int y);
}
class Liquid implements Layer {
    public Liquid() {
        ...
    }
    public void init(LayerType ltype, int x, int y) {
        ...
    }
}
class Solid implements Layer {
    public Solid() {
        ...
    }
    public void init(LayerType ltype, int x, int y) {
        ...
    }
}
```

With this setup in place you could do this:

```
public Class generateBlock(LayerType ltype, int x, int y) {
    if (...) return Liquid.class;
    if (...) return Solid.class;
    ...
}
```

The caller would initialize the layer as follows:

```
Layer layer = (Layer)generator
    .generateBlock(ltype, x, y)
    .newInstance();
layer.init(ltype, x, y);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just do it in the traditional OOP style.

First define an interface for a factory class

```
public interface BlockFactory {
    Block createInstance(int x, int y, LayerType ltype);
}
```

And then define corresponding factories

```
public class HoleBlockFactory implements BlockFactory {

    public Block createInstance(int x, int y, LayerType ltype) {
        return new HoleBlock(x, y);
    }
}


public class GrassBlockFactory implements BlockFactory {
    public Block createInstance(int x, int y, LayerType ltype) {
        return new GrassBlock(x, y);
    }
}
```

Finally in your generator first you get a factory in your switch statement and the use the factory to create objects when you need:

```
public class FlatGenerator implements Generator {

      @Override
      public BlockFactory generateBlock(LayerType ltype, int x, int y) {
        switch (ltype) {
          case Liquid:
            return new HoleBlockFactory();
          case Solid:
            return new GrassBlockFactory();

          default:
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }
      }

    }
}

public class World {

      Generator generator = ...;

      // ...

      private void generateBlocks(int x, int y) {
        for (LayerType ltype : LayerType.values())

          setblock(generator.generateBlock(ltype, x, y).createInstance(x, y, ltype), //.new() is as an example
             x, y, ltype);
      }

}
```

Comment: I was actually thinking about this - however, I would have to create twice as many classes for one object, _and_ the factory class contains a lot of code that is just copy-paste; replace "NullBlock" with "GrassBlock" or "AirBlock" etc.

Comment: That's just an example. You can of course combine your classes into one if you find it looking too complex. And personally I always prefer more classes than less classes. Small classes doing one thing each are much better than one big class doing lots of different things.